# Use of the prefix Im-

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, prefixes, prepositions

I have read the rules for using im- versus un- and agree with the general ideas put forth.  A word that I used recently, seems to fall into a category all its own.  The word is (im)provable, meaning not provable.  I Provable is an adjective, so is the opposite of provable (un)provable or (im)provable?  If it is (im)provable, that violates another meaning of the word, ie:  something that can be improved.  Or should it be nonprovable?

Comment: What are these rules - where did you read them?  Are you saying that 'imprint' is the opposite of 'print'?   Do you think 'imagine' is the opposite of 'agine'?  What about 'impish'?

Comment: imbecile, implode, impetuous etc.

Comment: Different _in_-. The word _improvable_ doesn't mean 'not capable of being proved', but rather 'capable of being improved'. SInce there's already a word _improve_ with a different _in_- prefix, the negative  _in_- prefix can't apply to _provable_. This is what _un_- is for.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of *provable* is *unprovable*:

> Unable to be demonstrated by evidence or argument as true or existing

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unprovable